# JavaFX JSBridge doesn't work after page load

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

I have a strange problem; JSBridge doesn't work after the page loads but it does when the button is clicked.

Test site:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#A0BEC4">
        <input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()"><br><br>

        <script>
            window.onload = function() { //does not work
                stb.play("hello3"); 
            }

            function play() { // work
                stb.play("hello2"); 
            }

            window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                stb.play("hello4"); //does not work
            });

            stb.play("hello"); //does not work

            function checkJSBridge(){ // !!! WORK !!! 
                if (typeof (stb.play) === "function") {
                    stb.play("WORK");
                    clearTimeout(bridge_timer);
                }
            }

            let bridge_timer = setTimeout(checkJSBridge, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My code (JavaFX 18.0.1 and JDK 18.0.1.1):

```
private WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
private Worker<?> engineWorker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
private JSBridge bridge = new JSBridge();

@Override
public final void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    engineWorker.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                jsobj.setMember("stb", bridge);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: At the time the line marked `//does not work` is executed, the page is not loaded.  The page is loaded when it receives a [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the answer. I tried the way you suggested but it doesn't work. If you run the html code, you can see that there will be 3 errors. When running this html in my javafx application, these errors should not occur, since these methods are in the application, but they are not called. They only work when a button is pressed.

Comment: This seems fairly natural to me. The load worker is a worker who’s task is to load the page. It’s only going to change to its succeeded state when the entire loading process has finished. From the perspective of the web engine, it will need to notify the JavaScript handler of the load event when loading is complete. That’s going to happen on the same thread (part of the task) that loads the page. Consequently, the JavaScript onLoaded event is going to fire *before* the load worker changes to the succeeded state. So you’re trying to access `stb` before it gets initialized.

Comment: So you can just reverse the responsibilities. Eg in JavaScript define `function sayHello() { return “Hello3”;}` and then in your handler on the load worker just do `System.out.println(webEngine.executeScript(“sayHello()”));`. If needed, you can use a JavaScript `onload` handler to set some variables and return those values from a function, instead of returning hard-coded values.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the answer. I figured out with your help that JSBridge is loaded after stb.play is called, so this doesn't work. I tried to make a loop with a check for the existence of the stb.play method. When it exists, then call stb.play(). This works as well as your suggestion. Thanks for the help!